# Firefox icon is blank, but can still be clicked on | Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, icons

I turned on my computer tonight and I now have a transparent Firefox icon for no apparent reason. I checked in a program called Menu Editor, but the Firefox icon shows up fine in it.
[image]

Comment: Try `sudo snap remove firefox` followed by `sudo snap install firefox`.

Comment: You have been working with .desktop files in your ~/.local/share/applications directory. Correct the file for Firefox that resides there, or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The icon shown in the application overview is defined in the `.desktop` launcher for the application. Your screenshot reveals that you have a `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop` file. It will override your systemwide `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop` file.

An error in your local `.desktop` launcher is causing no icon to be displayed. The easiest way will probably be to delete `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop`. Else, inspect its contents and correct the reference to the icon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Deleting `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop` as @vanadium mentioned did not work for me as now Firefox was no longer able to be found when searching for it in Gnome.

The reason for the icon breakage is that the `.local` desktop file doesn't update the location of the icon when a new version of Firefox snap is installed. So at some point

```
Icon=/snap/firefox/1551/default256.png
```

references a file that no longer exists, causing a blank icon.

To fix this you can simply change the path to

```
Icon=/snap/firefox/current/default256.png
```

where

```
/snap/firefox/current/
```

is a symlink that should always point to the newest Firefox install.

Alternatively you can copy the icon to a location where it wouldn't change.
(I opted to keep it in the same directory as the desktop file in my home folder.)

With this the referenced icon should persist over updates.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I previously created a custom launcher and the path to the icon had subsequently changed. There should be a symlink called `current` in `/snap/firefox/` which points to the latest folder.  If so, editing `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop` and changing `Icon=/snap/firefox/xxxx/default256.png` to `Icon=/snap/firefox/current/default256.png` should fix the issue.